# Couchdb update array sending json object in update function

Tags: curl, couchdb

I'm trying to update and array passing a json object or variables and build the json in the function. Which is the best way to do it?

For example, the function which I use to send variables and build the json:

```
function(doc,req){ 
var name = req.query.name; 
var number = req.query.number;
var channel = {"name":"" , "number" : ""};
channel.name = name;
channel.number = number;
doc.channels.push(channel); 
return[doc, channel + ' added'];}
```

**curl -X PUT https://server/db/_design/doc/_update/addChannel/channels?name=myChannel&number=23**

But what I got is just this in the array:

```
{
    "name": "myChannel"
}
```

Why the second variable is not there?

Is it possible to pass a json object in the url like : channels?json={}...  ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you forgot to enclose the url in single quotes. The presence of the & indicates to your shell that it should run the command in the background (and the 'number=23' part is simply ignored).

try;

```
curl -X PUT 'https://server/db/_design/doc/_update/addChannel/channels?name=myChannel&number=23'
```

and I suspect it will work.

I'll also note that the function could be written more simply as;

```
function(doc,req) {
  doc.channels.push({"name":req.query.name, "number": parseInt(req.query.number)});
  return [doc, channel + ' added'];
}
```

Note that the "23" will be passed as a string, so I added a parseInt call also.

Comment: But is it possible to pass a JSON object? like:


    curl -X PUT 'https://server/db/_design/doc/_update/addChannel/channels?json={"name":"foo","channel":23}'

I think { } and " will be a problem...

The function will looks like:

    function(doc,req) {
      doc.channels.push(req.query.json);
      return [doc, json + ' added'];
    }

??

Comment: It'll arrive as a string but you could always pass it through JSON.parse to get an object.